# AU Instrument Example doesn't handle note off event when DAW playhead skipped ahead

Tags: audio, xcode, midi, logic

Running the AU Instrument example provided with Xcode (it's a sine wave generator), it doesn't seem to receive the note off event when the playhead is skipped ahead in the DAW (Logic, for me).

I'm running a separate MIDI Monitor application, and it receives a MIDI note off message when I skip ahead, however, the AU Instrument doesn't receive the note off message.

If the AU instrument example DID receive the MIDI note off event, then it would stop playing the sine signal, however it continues to play the note indefinitely.

---

Edit:
Looking back, I assumed that Logic *is expected to* send a midi note-off for midi notes currently playing on an instrument track when the playhead is skipped ahead.  This is not the case.

The solution that I received in the Apple dev forums is posted below. The solution seems to me to be the correct audio unit programmatic solution.

Comment: Does it use Running Status? Is it sending note off or note on vel=0? Either way, if you determine it to be a bug, you need to report it to Apple.

Comment: Does the AU Instrument use Running Status?  I'm not sure.  There's some abstraction done by CoreMidi, so each midi message I receive is wrapped in an object/struct, and it always has the status byte.  In the case of the AU Instrument sine wave example, it receives Note On with velocity > 0, followed by no Note Off.  The MIDI Monitor app I'm using is monitoring a MIDI track with the same midi data as the AU Instrument track.  It receives Note On (vel 111) followed by Note Off (vel 0).

Comment: I posted this issue on the Apple developer boards

Comment: For some reason, Logic sends a Program change (bank, program, options) MIDI message type to the AU Instrument whenever the playhead is moved.  Though not ideal, I'm experimenting with using this message to turn off all notes currently playing.   Reasoning: if I changed the current program on a physical synthesizer, I'd expect the sounds that are currently being played to stop (since the new patch sounds different than the old patch)

Comment: Sending init data on position change is probably a pref in Logic [possibly 2 prefs, init data & chase data.] I'm a Cubase user so not used to Logic. You shouldn't expect sending a new PC to stop all playing notes. That's not in the Midi spec & should be explicit if required. [There's a trick where you can send PC, note on, PC, note on, PC note off, PC note off & get two different voices on one channel simultaneously.] There are CCs for specific resets.

Comment: BTW, you can test for running status by putting a hardware monitor on the output. Note on vel 0 is the running status equivalent of Note off, btw. Not all devices [especially simple ones] can be expected to understand running status [they should, in this day & age, but it's not mandatory.] It sounds like you need to read up on Midi spec before blaming the tools ;))

Comment: I agree. I need more knowledge of both MIDI, as well as AU Instrument development.  Someone posted an answer that fixes the issue in the Apple developer forums.  I'm going to post that here as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer was posted in the Apple developer forums and fixed the issue I was having.  It seems like the correct programatic solution.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727261

> I think Logic sometimes calls the AU's reset() method instead of note-off, depending on how you are moving the playhead.
>
> Just override AUAudioUnit.reset() and reset the state of your AU (including releasing any held notes).